# Swift 3.1.1 compile error: unknown key 'SwiftImportAsNonGeneric'

Tags: swift, xcode9

Some time after upgrading to Xcode 9, I discovered that I was no longer able to build a Kitura-based project with the Swift 3.1.1 snapshot (which I have installed via [swiftenv](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv)).

When I ran `swift build`, some time into the build I would get:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.apinotes:8:28: error: unknown key 'SwiftImportAsNonGeneric'
  SwiftImportAsNonGeneric: true
                           ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Foundation'
```

It seems that there is a dependency between Swift and Xcode, and Xcode 9 is no longer fully compatible with Swift 3.1.1 (or earlier) snapshots.  I believe it may be because my project uses Foundation, and Foundation on Mac is provided as part of Xcode, whereas on Linux it is part of the Swift snapshot (via [swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation)).

Answer (score 0):

I did find *a* solution to this problem: If I keep a copy of Xcode 8.3.3 around (eg. in `/Applications/Xcode8.3.3.app`) then I can use `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode<version>.app/Contents/Developer` to select the appropriate one prior to building with SPM, and I can then build both Swift 3.1.1 and 4.0 projects on the same system.

However, this feels a bit clunky. Each time I build a project with the 'other' Swift version, I have to make sure I run `xcode-select`, or the build will fail. Is having multiple versions of Xcode the right solution in this case, or am I missing a trick with Xcode 9?

- note that if, like me, you upgraded Xcode via the App Store, previous versions of Xcode are still available from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/